# geom_text_repel() and geom_text() generating copies of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I used the code below to create 2 plots. The first plot resulted in the labels overlapping and the appearance of unwanted letters in the legend. So, in the plot 2, I used the `geom_text(show.legend = FALSE)` and `geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = Inf)` snippets to get around this situation. However, it doesn't work and still generates copies of the labels. I hope you can contribute with some solution or strategy that solves this situation.

```
# packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# creating dataframe
fruits <- c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'pear')
axis_x <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 4)
axis_y <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 4)
df <- data.frame(fruits, axis_x, axis_x)

# Plot 1
ggplot(df, aes(x = axis_x, y = axis_y, colour = fruits, label = fruits)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text()

# Plot 2
ggplot(df, aes(x = axis_x, y = axis_y, colour = fruits, label = fruits)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = Inf)
```

[image]
[image]

Pages accessed in an attempt to resolve the problem:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html
[Labeling with geom_text and geom_text_repel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910696/labeling-with-geom-text-and-geom-text-repel)
[How do I include strikethrough text in geom_text_repel or geom_text labels for ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819807/how-do-i-include-strikethrough-text-in-geom-text-repel-or-geom-text-labels-for-g)
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-texts-add-text-annotations-to-a-graph-in-r-software
...and many others

Comment: Remove `geom_text` from your code to get rid of the duplicates. Add `show.legend=FALSE` to `geom_text_repel`.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know I could use this inside geom_text_repel().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but I just stumbled over your post:
I use geom_text_repel like this to avoid overlaying points and letters in the legend:

```
geom_text_repel(label=rownames(df), show.legend = FALSE)
```

Then you should only see the legend from geom_point.